# try_files explained

Tags: nginx

I want a simple redirect. If the REQUEST_URI is "/", i want redirect to "/blog/".
After reading some Pitfall-Docs and BestPractices, i guess `try_files` is for what i search. But the [nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) doesnt clarify to me, how it works exactly. There are two (or one) path(s) and an uri? uri seems to be the REQUEST_URI which is what iam looking for. But i dont understand, how path1 (and path2) interacts with it. What is when evaluated. Can you help me to get the point?

P.S.: nginx version 1.0(.8)

Answer (score 2):

> There are two (or one) path(s) and an uri? **uri seems to be the
>   REQUEST_URI**

No. It is the fallback URI. `try_files path1 [path2] uri` check if `path1`, `path2` is exist. If it not, Nginx will redirect to the `uri`.

For example: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;` is equivalent to:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
   rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
```

Comment: There's one small difference between your rewrite and the try_files.  The rewrite will preserve the query string by default, and the try_files fallback will not.  You either need to add $is_args$args to the try_files /index.php or add ? to the rewrite /index.php to make them truly equivalent.

Comment: So, path1 and path2 are checked against the filesystem? and if these files not found, they assumed the last argument as uri to use??

Answer (score 1):

If you want a redirect, then `try_files` isn't what you want.  Try this:

```
rewrite ^/$ /blog/ redirect;
```

Comment: Okay - thanks a lot. But can you still clarify try_files? :)

Comment: Sure - basically, you give it a list of locations, and it can be as long as you want.  It will try to serve the request from each of those locations, in order, until it finds one that works.

Comment: It's better to use location = / { rewrite ^ /blog/ redirect; } or location = / { return 302 $scheme://$host/blog/; } than a server-level rewrite.  Also, saying that try_files is a list of locations is misleading, as it will only perform an internal redirect for the last argument, all the arguments before the last are literally checks for files on the filesystem, and if one is found, $uri is set appropriately before calling the location's content handler.

Comment: @kolbyjack then i get an too-many-redirect error (i tried the 2nd example)). location / will always get evaluated and initiate the redirect. Regardless if location /blog is before, after or inside location /. :/ what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you include the =?  location / and location = / mean very different things.